# How to store all entered array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new at programming. I have to write a code, main requirements - user chooses the sorting method (one is already added, the second one I will add later), enters the amount of elements in the array, enters the elements and then the code sorts them. But it looks like the code only takes the last entered element and tries to sort it. What do I have to do to make it sort all entered elements?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("181RDB094 Līva Gundega Ermansone 1");
        System.out.print("method:");
        int M;
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            M = sc.nextInt();
        else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("count:");
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        int[] masīvs = new int[count];
        System.out.println("items:");
        masīvs = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            masīvs[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("result:");
        if (M == 1) {
            int[] b = new int[count];
            int[] less = new int[count];
            int[] equal = new int[count];
            int k;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    if (masīvs[i] == masīvs[j]) {
                        equal[i] = i++;
                    } else if (masīvs[i] > masīvs[j]) {
                        less[i] = i++;
                    }
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                k = less[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < equal[i]; j++) {
                    b[k + j] = masīvs[i];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                masīvs[i] = b[i];
                System.out.print(masīvs[i] + " ");
            }
        } else if (M == 2) {
        } else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the ugly code, it's just a draft.

Expected:

```
181RDB094 Līva Gundega Ermansone 1
method:1
count:4
items:
13
31
55
2

result:
55 31 13 2
```

Actual results:

```
181RDB094 Līva Gundega Ermansone 1
method:1
count:4
items:
13
31
55
2
result:
2 2 2 0
```

Comment: I would recommend using a debugger to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple for loop after filling your array to check the contents. There, you can see that all entries are written into the array correctly.

This will output:

`Array:13`
`Array:31`
`Array:55`
`Array:2`

```
for (int i = 0; i < masīvs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Array:" + masīvs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorting method you are following fixes a set of equal elements at their proper position by finding the no of elements less than those elements.

The problem in sorting lies in finding the no of elements less and equal to.

`equal[i]++;` instead of `equal[i]=i++;`

Similarly,

`less[i]++;` instead of `less[i]=i++;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Java 8** or more recent, you may be able to use the [*ArrayList*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class (with the [*Integer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class) instead of an 1D array (i.e. `int[] var = new int[x]`); it would allow you to use its [`sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method instead.

You would have to create a [*Comparator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instance (lambda function, or anonymous) or an implementing class, unless you want to use the natural ordering of those.

It would give you something around those two lines:
 `ArrayList<Integer> var = new ArrayList<>();` 
and `var.sort();` (assuming you use the natural ordering)

It might however be harder to manipulate at first, if you're new to the *Java Collection Framework*, so don't hesitate to ask questions.

---

P.S.: I might have misunderstood the code, so just tell me so I can fix my answer.

P.S.S.: Somewhat unrelated, and it's probably in your mind (ignore that part then), but I would recommend you to refactor that into much more smaller methods/functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code organization is very bad. It's easier to give you more correct solution, than count and fix your problem:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final BiFunction<int[], Comparator<Integer>, int[]> sort =
                (items, comparator) -> Arrays.stream(items)
                                             .boxed()
                                             .sorted(comparator)
                                             .mapToInt(i -> i)
                                             .toArray();


        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            Comparator<Integer> comparator = getSortingMethod(scan);
            int[] items = getItems(scan);
            int[] sorted = sort.apply(items, comparator);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
        }
    }

    private static final Comparator<Integer> SORT_ASC = Comparator.naturalOrder();
    private static final Comparator<Integer> SORT_DESC = Comparator.reverseOrder();
    private static final Comparator<Integer> SORT_NULL = (one, two) -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input-output error");
    };

    private static Comparator<Integer> getSortingMethod(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("181RDB094 Līva Gundega Ermansone 1");
        System.out.print("method:");

        try {
            int M = scan.nextInt();

            if (M == 1)
                return SORT_DESC;
            if (M == 2)
                return SORT_ASC;
            return SORT_NULL;
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            return SORT_NULL;
        }
    }

    private static int[] getItems(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.print("count:");
        int[] items = new int[scan.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("items:");

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            items[i] = scan.nextInt();

        return items;
    }

}
```